# Algorithm header llrint, llround compiler error

Tags: c++, eclipse, algorithm, gcc

I'm learning C++ and I'm at the point of using the <algorithm> header and I get this compiler error even with an empty project:

```
/Users/italrolando/hpc-gcc47/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/cmath:1108:11: error: '::llrint' has not been declared
/Users/italrolando/hpc-gcc47/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/cmath:1109:11: error: '::llrintf' has not been declared
/Users/italrolando/hpc-gcc47/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/cmath:1110:11: error: '::llrintl' has not been declared
/Users/italrolando/hpc-gcc47/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/cmath:1112:11: error: '::llround' has not been declared
/Users/italrolando/hpc-gcc47/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/cmath:1113:11: error: '::llroundf' has not been declared
/Users/italrolando/hpc-gcc47/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/cmath:1114:11: error: '::llroundl' has not been declared

make: *** [algorithm.o] Error 1
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char ** argv ){

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Eclipse with GCC 4.7.1 compiler and it's quite strange since the course I'm following is using Eclipse with Gcc 4.7 and it works.

Thanks

Comment: it seems that your compiler is not installed correctly

Comment: Can you reproduce if you invoke `gcc 4.7.1` from the command line?

Comment: @merlin2011 when I invoke gcc from the command line, is called gcc 4.2.1 (I'm on SL with Xcode 4.2), I hope is that what you meant. The 4.7.1 is in the home root as my course.

Comment: I meant to try to invoke 4.7.1 from the command line by using its absolute path. More specifically, try to compile the code above using it

Comment: @merlin2011 no compiling error appear. There must be something wrong on Eclipse.